# When to use `method_missing`

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In the code below, method `roar` is not defined in class `Lion`, but still can be called using `method_missing`.

```
class Lion
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    puts "Lion will #{name}: #{args[0]}"
  end
end

lion = Lion.new
lion.roar("ROAR!!!") # => Lion will roar: ROAR!!!
```

In which situations and how should I use this `method_missing`? And is it safe to use?

Comment: Ghost method, usually a metaprogramming tool, I guess. Be careful about efficiency. Ghost method is slow.

Comment: I think you mean `class Lion` rather than `Class Lion`.

Comment: @EricWalker: thanks, typing mistake.

Comment: @EricWalker -- Really, dude?

Comment: @DylanRichards Yes, using lowercase `class` is necessary. In Ruby, `class` is a keyword like `if` or `def`, while `Class` is the name of a class. `Class Lion` will result in a `NameError: uninitialized constant Lion`.

Answer (score 9):

It's entirely *safe* to use provided you use it in expected ways and don't get carried away. Not everything you can do is worth doing, after all.

The advantage of `method_missing` is you can respond to all kinds of things in unique ways.

The disadvantage is you don't advertise your capabilities. Other objects that expect you to `respond_to?` something will not get confirmation and might treat your custom object in ways you don't intend.

For building Domain Specific Languages and providing very loose glue between components, this sort of thing is invaluable.

A great example of where this is a good fit is the Ruby [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) class.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `method_missing`'s twin brother `responds_to?`

Comment: Actually, `method_missing`'s twin brother is `respond_to_missing?` You should *always* override both of them together.

Comment: @JörgWMittag never heard of `respond_to_missing` is that a gem!?

Comment: @akuhn: it's in stdlib: [Object#respond_to_missing?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks! Must be a 1.9 method, not present on my 1.8.7 installation on OSX.

Comment: The question is _when_ to use method missing. The only correct answer is (almost) never. 

Comment: @Todd I use it all the time. It's very handy for implementing proxies and other wrappers, such as when writing a DSL.

Answer (score 8):

**Summary:** When to use? When it will make your life easier **and** not complicate others' lives.

---

Here's one example that pops to mind. It's from [redis_failover](https://github.com/ryanlecompte/redis_failover) gem.

```
# Dispatches redis operations to master/slaves.
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if redis_operation?(method)
    dispatch(method, *args, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Here we check if the method called is actually a command of redis connection. If so, we delegate it to underlying connection(s). If not, relay to super.

Another famous example of `method_missing` application is ActiveRecord finders.

```
User.find_by_email_and_age('me@example.com', 20)
```

There's not, of course, a method `find_by_email_and_age`. Instead, the `method_missing` breaks the name, analyzes the parts and invokes `find` with proper parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a favorite of mine

```
class Hash
  def method_missing(sym,*args)
    fetch(sym){fetch(sym.to_s){super}}
  end
end
```

Which lets me access values of a hash as if they were attributes. This is particular handy when working with JSON data.

So for example, rather than having to write `tweets.collect{|each|each['text']}` I can just write `tweets.collect(&:text)` which is much shorter. Or also, rather than `tweets.first['author']` I can just write `tweets.first.author` which feels much more natural. Actually, it gives you Javascript-style access to values of a hash.

NB, *I'm expecting the monkey patching police at my door any minute…*

Comment: You could also write a method that emits procedures, like `tweets.collect(&attr('text'))` which would be: `def attr(a); lambda { |e| e[a] }; end`

Comment: You’re right, but then I cannot write `tweets.first.text` (updated my post).

Comment: Instead of rolling your own, why not use OpenStruct? Creating a "naked" object is tricky to do yourself. If you have keys like `hash` it will conflict with internal methods.

Comment: @tadman JSON.parse(file) does not create OpenStruct but Hash instances, hence my monkey patch.

Comment: Eleven years later: Ruby JSON api has `object_class`, so you can return an OpenStruct :D

https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/json#module-JSON-label-Parsing+Options

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost, stick to Sergio Tulentsev's summary.

Apart from that, I think looking at examples is the best way to get a feeling for right and wrong situations for `method_missing`; so here is another simple example:

I recently made use of `method_missing` in a [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

- The Null Object was a replacement for a Order model.
- The Order stores different prices for different currencies.

---

Without `method_missing` it looks like this:

```
class NullOrder
  def price_euro
    0.0
  end

  def price_usd
    0.0
  end

  # ...
  # repeat for all other currencies
end
```

---

With `method_missing`, I can shorten it to:

```
class NullOrder
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)  
    m.to_s =~ /price_/ ? 0.0 : super
  end
end
```

With the added benefit of not having to (remember to) update the `NullOrder` when I add new `price_xxx` attributes to `Order`.

Answer (score 3):

I also found a blog post from (Paolo Perrotta) where it demonstrated when to use method_missing:

```
class InformationDesk
  def emergency
    # Call emergency...
    "emergency() called"
  end

  def flights
    # Provide flight information...
    "flights() called"
  end

  # ...even more methods
end
```

Check if a service has been asked during lunch time.

```
class DoNotDisturb
  def initialize
    @desk = InformationDesk.new
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    unless name.to_s == "emergency"
      hour = Time.now.hour
      raise "Out for lunch" if hour >= 12 && hour < 14
    end

    @desk.send(name, *args)
  end
end

# At 12:30...
DoNotDisturb.new.emergency # => "emergency() called"
DoNotDisturb.new.flights # ~> -:37:in `method_missing': Out for lunch (RuntimeError)
```