# What is the purpose of overriding method_missing method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Going through "Well Grounded Rubyist" book. In chapter 4, it goes through examples as to how you could override the `method_missing` method. What it doesnt explain very well is why you want to do this in the first place? What is the purpose of overriding `method_missing` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use \`method\_missing\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759902/when-to-use-method-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which `Well Grounded Rubyist` edition you're reading (consider switching to the second one), but the latter actually gives you an idea of what `method_missing` can be used for. **Listing 4.13** at page 113 provides you with an idea of combining bunch of a slightly similar methods like

```
class Person
  def all_with_children
    # some select...
  end
  def all_with_parents
    # seems like another select but joined with another table...
  end
  def all_with_cars
    # the same here...
  end
  def all_with_house
    # woah, four methods doing slightly the same!
  end
  # so what if you have 100 database attributes and want to 
  # provide a selector for all of them?
end
```

And replacing them with some metaprogramming using `method_missing`:

```
def self.method_missing m, *args
  method = m.to_s
  if method.start_with? ("all_with_")
  # now we know that we're going to do SELECT.
  # the only thing to consider is what table should be joined.
  # we defer that from the right part of the method name
  # e.g. "children" for "all_with_children"
  # in case we gonna ask for "all_with_wife" we won't need to add new method!
end
```

Prior to `Ruby on Rails 4` it was a common pattern to call something like `Person.find_by_username` which implied the same `method_missing` logics.

Think of `method_missing` as a method which gives you an opportunity to do something before an application fails due to unknown method call.

You could desire to add some debug information on failure (log an extended error description to the logfile, or send a email to admin that something goes wrong).

`method_missing` could give you an ability to define your own getters/setters methods for all attributes with just a couple of lines.

In short, it gives you one more opportunity to write short and readable code. Note that it should not be abused though, as you have some price to pay for its usage (both overall code comlexity and execution time).

Answer (score 2):

This is required for metaprogramming when one does not know in advance, what methods are “expected” on that object.

Naïve example (implement `attr_reader` for *all* instance variables for *all* derived classes):

```
class A
  def method_missing m, *args, &cb
    return instance_variable_get(:"@#{m}") if instance_variables.include? :"@#{m}"
    super
  end
end

class B < A
  def initialize
    @b = 42
  end
end

B.new.b
#⇒ 42
```

For more complicated examples, one might look into Rails code, that is full of `method_missing`s.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if you wanted to dynamically respond to methods without defining them in advance or because a set of method names use similar/same code for a list of possibilities.

As an example, you could have different classes that have a set price, but you want to easily add conversions for a large set of currencies.  So you could do:  obj.price_euro,  obj.price_usd, etc..  and all of this could be caught by method_missing.

This doesn't make it necessarily a good or bad idea.

Note that if you override method_missing, you'll be much slower than a "def method", and don't forget to update respond_to? to match!

Comment: Another example is the way that Rails provides methods such as:  car.find_by_owner, car.find_by_year, etc..  

That's not to say that this is how Rails implements these methods - there are other ways to dynamically define methods and I have a feeling Rails uses something more clever than method_missing, though I haven't read the source yet.